# Extract extended property in logging formatter

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

Is it possible to extract a specific extended property.

So that only TransactionID is extracted from the properties dictionary

I tried to do the following but it just printed {TransactionID} repeadetly for each property.

```
{dictionary({TransactionID} - {value})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use keyvalue to log individual keys from the ExtendedProperties:

TransactionID - {keyvalue(TransactionID)}